# The search parameter is added to all other links

Tags: php, wordpress

search.php code

```
global $query_string;
    $query_args = explode("&", urldecode($query_string));
    
    $search_query = array();
    $search_t = '';

    if ($query_string) {
        foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
            $query_split = explode("=", $string);
            $search_query[$query_split[0]] = $query_split[1];
        }
        $search_t = $search_query['s'];
    }
```

`example.com/?s=example`

Why search param `/?s=example` added to another links

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this. I tried the `remove_query_arg()` function. But it doesn't work.